# OpenMP how to parallel incrementing loop

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have two arrays:

```
  double arrayA[N+2];
  double arrayB[N+2];
```

How can I loop this in parallel using OpenMP?

```
 for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    arrayA[i] += arrayA[i+2] + sin(arrayB[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume arrayA is prepopulated with meaningful values, right?
If yes, save a copy of arrayA to a temporary *tmp* array and implement a simple openmp for pragma.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i=0; i<N; i++){
   arrayA[i] = arrayA[i] + tmp[i+2] + sin(arrayB[i]);
}
```